# Get value of a submitted form without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to upload an image without submit button. My code works fine for submiting without button.

My HTML code

```
<form name="service_image_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 Add new image <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" onchange="return subForm()" /> 
</form>

<script>
function subForm() {
document.service_image_form.submit();
};
</script>
```

But I'm little confused in retriving data at PHP. 
In php I tried something like this to retrieve data.

```
if (isset($_POST['service_image_form']))
{
echo "working";
}
```

Here I'm trying to echo "working" just for confirmation. If my condition works then then I can save my image to server and db. I know its very simple but stumbed here for a while. surfed lots of links, but no idea. Please help me out with this.

I know if I had a submit button with name="submit" then I can retrive like this

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 upload code comes here..
 }
```

I dont wan't submit button..

Comment: Remove `name="service_image_form"` from your `<form>` and rename `name="userfile"` to `name="service_image_form"` - you will also need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to `<form` then change `isset($_POST['service_image_form']` to `isset($_FILES['service_image_form']`

Comment: Thanq @Fred-ii- ..made changes Working perfectly. Simple issue but confused.

Comment: You're welcome Rakesh.

Comment: Let me know if you would like the question closed, using the comment to answer option. *The choice is yours*.

Comment: yes my issue resolved. @Fred-ii- .. But started hating stackoverflow.. Its not a suitable place for beginners.. those who  can swim only get life boats.. those who needs life boats here will sink..

Comment: People can be rather strange animals at times, I being one too. It depends on the time of the day a question's posted, how long people have been coding for certain lengths of time. The original concept on how Stack came about, and I'm not the one making it up, was conceived by professionals for professionals. I didn't think your question was that bad, but in retrospect, when a person gives you a working solution based on a comment, the person who gave the comment for a solution, should've been asked to put in an answer. See the timestamps on both my comment and the answer you accepted.

Comment: ya its my fault.. Left office.. And didn't made proper response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a post request is made:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    echo "working";
}
```

Note that uploaded files data will be in the `$_FILES` superglobal, not `$_POST`, and as mentioned by Fred, you will need to add the enctype attribute on your form

Answer (score 1):

You need to add enctype attribute into your for like this

```
<form name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 Add new image <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" onchange="return subForm()" /> 
</form>
```

And in your php you get the uploaded files using the $_FILE

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0) {
  echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
} else {
  echo 'Name: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  echo 'Temp file location in: ' . $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I forgot to add enctype in my question. My code working perfectly now.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are trying to check if upload is correct, right? Well, it's not how it's done.

PHP has great manual for that http://php.net/manual/pl/features.file-upload.php

You miss:

- correct form encoding, add attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag
- your file will be placed in $_FILES['userfile'] variable
- you can check $_FILES['userfile']['error'] to determine if upload was successful (if so, it will be equal to constant UPLOAD_ERR_OK, 0)

After that you are good to go, you can find all the details here http://php.net/manual/pl/features.file-upload.post-method.php it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Rafal Nowak.. My image upload already worked fine. But I confused when I tried to upload without submit button. Because I always use **if (isset($_POST(["submit"]))** to retrieve submited vales. Now I understood the $_SERVER concept and my issue resolved. Thanks for helping.